# Hi.I want to capture video while its playing.Frames are repeating

Tags: android, camera, frame, video-capture, android-video-player

I want to capture a video while its playing.For example whenever user want to capture their favorite scene they can capture that particular scene.I used below way.It was capturing a image but not correctly.am getting only first frame every time.Pls help me to solve this issue

```
      MediaMetadataRetriever mediaMetadataRetriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
            mediaMetadataRetriever.setDataSource(videoList.get(videoPosition).getPlayerData());
            pausePosition=mp.getCurrentPosition();
            if(mp.isPlaying())
            {
                mp.pause();
                playVideo.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_play_white_24dp);
            }
            Bitmap bmFrame = mediaMetadataRetriever
                    .getFrameAtTime(mp.getCurrentPosition() * 1000,MediaMetadataRetriever.OPTION_CLOSEST_SYNC);
```

Comment: Means you have to Capture a video screen while video is Running...??

Comment: @SagarAghara yes.u are correct.I am trying it for a day.

Comment: @SagarAghara I used Surfaceview with media player.Pls help if u know about it

Comment: yes bro. wait some time...i am checking.

Comment: @SagarAghara ok.are you in any chat of stackoverflow.we can discuss about it

Comment: Hey see you know  android-gpuimageplus master  Libs on GitHub

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133633/discussion-between-sagar-aghara-and-lavanya-lavan).